# Using groupby in Pandas by aggregating the columns differently

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataFrame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([["John", 1234 , 10], 
                    ["John",1234, 5] , 
                    ["Sally" , 1235 , 20] , 
                    ["Sally" , 1235, 5]], 
columns = ["Name", "ID", "Amount"])
```

I want to group this dataFrame by Name. I could do:

```
group = df.groupby('Name').agg('sum')
```

Which would give me:

```
         ID  Amount
Name               
John   2468      15
Sally  2470      25
```

However, I want to aggregate the columns by *'count'* for column **ID** and *'sum'* for column **Amount**. Which will look like:

```
         ID  Amount
Name               
John     2      15
Sally    2      25
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby('Name').agg({'ID': 'count', 'Amount': 'sum'})
       Amount  ID
Name             
John       15   2
Sally      25   2
```